# How to set SelectedIndex?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have tried to set the SelectedIndex property to 0 so that "Read" shows up when the user control renders, but it is not working. It doesn't show anything, but when I click on the combo box, I do see all my items.

Is there something I'm missing?

My XAML code:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=DataMode}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Read"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Subscribe"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` property binding is overriding the selection.

Approach 1 - Change the binding `Mode` to `OneWayToSource` if you don't want to set `Combobox` item from VM.

```
 <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=DataMode, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Read"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Subscribe"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Approach 2 - Remove `SelectedIndex` from xaml and set `Text` through property.

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=DataMode}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="20" Width="100" >
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Read"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Subscribe"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

In VM -

```
private string dataMode;
    public string DataMode
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataMode))
            {
                return "Read";
            }

            return dataMode;
        }
        set
        {
            dataMode = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DataMode");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, Its works. Thank you. 
I tried with events and it was working too. but its wrong way isn't it? 

  private void ComboboxMode_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            ComboboxMode.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

Comment: Welcome, binding are always preferred over events in WPF(MVVM).

Comment: well I have just changed to this.. Text="{Binding Path=DataMode, Mode=OneWayToSource}"> and its working.